# Php json parse slashes and quotes

Tags: php, json

I'm new in php, I've never seen a json file with slashes and quotes before.

```
{
    "datas": "{\"_id\":{\"testid\":[14,49]},\"newid\":44235,\"type\":{\"_id\":3,\"name\":\"umbrella\"}}"
}
```

I tried codes like this but it didn't work

```
$url = '/test.json';
 
$json = file_get_contents($url);
 
$arr = json_decode($json);

foreach($arr->datas AS $data){
    echo $data->name;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `datas` is JSON as well, so you need to decode that string after decoding the overall JSON.

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
$datas = json_decode($arr->datas);
```

As the element you are after isn't in an array and is just the property of an object, you can access it using...

```
echo $datas->type->name;
```